# Ruby - include? returning false when object is indeed in array

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, include

```
my_hash = Hash.new{|h,k| h[k] = []}
name = 'John'
my_hash[name] << '7'
my_hash[name] << '9'
name = 'Jane'
my_hash[name] << '7'
my_hash[name] << 'J'

array_info = my_hash.values_at('John')
puts array_info.class                   => array 
array_info.each do |ele|
   puts ele                             => 7, 9
end
removed = array_info.include?('7')
puts removed                           => false ??!?!?????
```

array_info just printed 7 as an element in the array, so we know that it exists.  So why would array_info.include?('7') not return true??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at array_info. Puts-ing it shows that your ele values are indeed in that array, but your array is nested inside another array.

```
removed = array_info.first.include?('7')
```

Will return true.